# In a network do we need both TLS and Firewall?

Tags: tls, firewalls

I need to set up a small network as shown below. Is it really required that the "switch should also host a firewall" when all the communication between the "computers" is over TLS?

[image]

Comment: is your switch L2 or L3?

Comment: No firewall or TLS is ever "required" (unless someone else requires them of you). These things are tools to manage risk. Whether you need a firewall or TLS depends on what risks you want to manage. What bad things do you want to prevent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because they have very different functions. A firewall permits specific types of traffic while blocking unwanted traffic. TLS ensures that data exchanged between hosts is encrypted, so eavesdropping is not possible.

A firewall won't encrypt traffic between nodes, and TLS won't stop unwanted traffic from reaching nodes.

Comment: I agree that, we need a firewall for communication between the Computer and the external network (via router).
Do I need a firewall for the traffic between the Computers A, B, C, D?
Note: All these computers are trusted nodes.

Comment: I'd still apply a firewall, but this is a bit of a personal choice, where many factors come into account (risks, maintainability, etc). What if a new untrusted device is connected to the switch? The firewall rules on your routers won't block traffic from that device to the nodes. If that's a plausible scenario, I'd consider having at least a basic set of firewall rules on each node.

Answer (score 0):

If switch operates on L2 layer only, then switch should not run firewall and you should split your network using VLANs. Computer A must be assigned to LAN1, for example and Computer B, C and D assigned to VLAN2. And link between switch and router passes only VLAN 1 over trunk. Firewalls should be applied on end hosts and router. L2 switch should do switching only.

If it is L3 switch (with routing capabilities) then yes, it acts as router and should use firewall to filter unwanted traffic.